# Help me understand how to use a class in OOP C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm creating an application that basically downloads and uploads files from various types of locations. I asked some advice on here and I was told that I should take an Object Oriented Approach with something like this, but this is my first real usage of OOP so I'm having a hard time understanding how to carry out what I want. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class FileListClass
    {
        public string sourcetype;
        public string source;
        public string destination;
        public string destinationtype;
        public bool deleteSource;
    }
```

How do I actually enter a file into here in my main method? When I create a new list based on this class, .Add on the list requires an item of 'FileListClass' type - how do I create this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do some thing lik ethis

```
FileListClass oFileListClass = new  FileListClass();
oFileListClass.sourcetype="";
oFileListClass.source="";
oFileListClass.destination="";
oFileListClass.destinationtype="";
oFileListClass.deleteSource=false;
```

this will create one object, and you can create as many as possible like this with diffrent values.

if you wana keep this in List then create list of type FileListClass  like

```
List<FileListClass > oListFileListClass = new  List<FileListClass >();
```

then add all of your objects in this like

```
oListFileListClass.Add(oFileListClass);
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```
var yourList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<FileListClass>();

yourList.Add(new FileListClass
             {
                 sourcetype = "...",
                 source = "...",
                 ...
             });
```

Longer answer:

The above should work, but do take note that your class is not particularly well-designed (IMHO). It's more of a simple data record/container than a  class that's "true" to OO principles. This may be just fine, depending on your requirements.

- It's uncommon to expose fields directly in C#. Usually, only properties are exposed:
   `public string SourceType { get; set; }`
- `sourcetype` and `destinationtype` are slightly suspect -- this *might* be a case where subclassing (class inheritance) might be suitable later on. Even without that, and without me knowing what exactly you're going to store in those two fields, have you considered using `enum`s for them instead of plain `string`s?
- In C#, it's common practice to name public members with `CamelCase` capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a bettere approach to define Enums for your constant types, something like

```
public enum SourceTypes
{
    Network = 0,
    WAN =1,
}
```

ecc. ecc.

then modify your FileLystClass as follows

```
public class FileListClass
{
    public SouceTypes sourceType;
    ...
    public DestinationTypes destinationType;
    ...
}
```

then, to answer your question.

You have defined a a class(a type) called FileListClass.
To use it, just create as many instance you want, populating the fields of the objects accordingly to your sources

```
public void CreateFileListList()
{
     for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
     {
         FileListClass flo = new FileListClass
         flo.sourceType = SourceTypes.WAN;
         flo.deletesource = true;
         [...]

         myList.add(flo);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest laying out the basic actions that are needed in your program:

```
DownloadFrom(String loc);
UploadFrom(String loc);
```

Then you can build lower levels of your app:

```
DownloadFrom(String loc);
    HTTPConnect();
    FTPConnect();
    etc..

UploadFrom(String loc);
    HTTPConnect();
    FTPConnect();
    etc..
```

At this point you can already have a feeling of the structure of your program, you can in fact create classes around your different actions:

```
class Connect {
    HTTPConnect();
    FTPConnect();
}

class Download : Connect{
    DownloadFrom(String loc);
}

class Upload : Connect{
    UploadFrom(String loc);
}
```

As you can see this is a first approach to OOP. There are many advantages to use a structure of Objects around your program but It would be too hard of an explanation. Try reading Google about it: [Advantages of OOP](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1665&bih=866&q=advantages+of+oop&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).